# winget process and command line switches for NSIS upgrade

Tags: nsis, winget

I have an NSIS installer and created a yaml manifest, and I need to handle upgrades.

When an upgrade is performed by winget, does it first run uninstall on the existing install, then the new downloaded installer?

If there is a specification on the switches to the different installer types (MSIX, INNO, NSIS, EXE etc) it would be very useful i cant seem to find the low level interface (on how winget calls the installers and switches) in the docs.

Comment: Your question is borderline but since you only used the two relevant tags (and not Windows, Installer etc) I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winget knows about the two standard NSIS switches `/S` and `/D=c:\install\path` if you specify `nullsoft` as the type in your manifest. I believe it also supports `/AllUsers` and `/CurrentUser`.

I don't think Winget will uninstall first. You can do that yourself in your installer on upgrades if you really need to.

Your Winget manifest can specify custom switches if you want to do something special in your installer when called from Winget.

Comment: Fantastic thank you! Any pointers to the custome switches documentation I couldn't see it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/package/manifest

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/blob/master/schemas/JSON/manifests/v1.3.0/manifest.singleton.1.3.0.json which is a horrible way to spec things, says InstallerSwitches -> Custom

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/tree/master/doc/manifest/schema is a more human readable explanation of the schema. It is possible to add "uninstallPrevious" in the manifest if it's necessary.